# Type hinting of returned entity in Doctrine2 repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpstorm

I have `CustomRepository` class which extends `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`. This repository is assosiated with many different entities.
There is a method in the repository which returns an associated entity.

```
class CustomRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    function getEntity() { ... } // returns an instance of associated entity
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CustomRepository")
 */
class EntityClass1 { ... }    
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CustomRepository")
 */
class EntityClass2 { ... }

$repo1 = $entityManager->getRepository('Entity1');
$entity1 = $repo1->getEntity(); // will return an instance of EntityClass1

$repo2 = $entityManager->getRepository('Entity2');
$entity2 = $repo1->getEntity(); // will return an instance of EntityClass2
```

I use Symfony 2 plugin, which correctly detects the class of returned by inherited methods entities as `find`.
Is there a way to inform the plugin that the method returns an assosiated entity?

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
/**
 * MyEntity repository.
 *
 * @method MyEntity[] find
 */
```

Comment: I'm sorry for lack of details. I added the code sample to describe roughly what I'm asking.

Comment: So you want type hint on the methods of your repository class ,right ? So for example `$entity2` is known as being of type `Entity2`

Comment: Yes, but the method itself returns entities of different classes (EntityClass1, EntityClass2 in the example). But there are a lot of such entities in the project (I use CustomRepository instead of EntityRepository for many entities), so the same method might return entities of different types...

Comment: But using the same repository for different entities is not a googd method, better to create a BaseRepository and create Entity1Repository and Entity2Repository that extends this new one. Then add the @method annotations as suggested in my answer in both new Entity repositories.